# Inserting elements in a specific positions in the existing array

Tags: arrays, scala, array-algorithms

I have a List and Map as below,

```
 val exampleList = List("A","B","C","D","E","A","L","M","N")
 val exampleMap = Map("W1" -> Vector(4,8),
                      "W2"  -> Vector(5),
                      "W3" -> Vector(9))
```

So I need to add all the letters in the exampleMap to the exampleList according to the values (indexes that should take places in the exampleList) that in the exampleMap. So the final output should be something like this
 `val result = List("A","B","C","D","W1","E","W2","A","L","M","W1","N","W3")`

I tried several ways using foldLeft as well as using flatMap but still not get any luck.

Comment: Will there be repetition? For eg: "W4" -> Vector(4). If so what should be done?

Comment: Also what about out-of-index values? In this case, there is a value in the 9th pos, what if there is one in 11th?

Comment: Something I don't understand is, after inserting `W1` in the `4` index, then the next element should be the `5` index, thus `W2`, but rather you insert `E` and then `W2` which is now in the `6` index rather than the `5`

Answer (score 0):

I am making two assumptions

1. There won't be any repetition. For eg: "W4" -> Vector(4).
2. At the most one value is to be placed beyond the size.

To solve, I would first change exampleMap as follows,

```
//Map(4 -> W1, 8 -> W1, 5 -> W2, 9 -> W3)
val modifiedExampleMap = exampleMap.flatMap { case (k, v) =>
  v.map(_ -> k)
}
```

and then use it to create the final list.

```
exampleList.view.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) {
  case (acc, (elem, index)) =>
    modifiedExampleMap.get(index + 1) match {
      case Some(value) => value :: elem :: acc
      case None => elem :: acc
    }
}.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this solution needs to be supported for the example map like this

  val exampleMap = Map("W1" -> Vector(4, 8),
    "W2" -> Vector(5, 11),
    "W3" -> Vector(9, 10))

and the output should be something like this

List(A, B, C, D, W1, E, W2, A, L, M, W1, N, W3, W2, W3)

Comment: Btw, your first assumption is correct. but regarding the second assumption, there will be more positions that are beyond the size of exampleList

Comment: @Hima_93, will there be missing values? Eg: `"W2 -> Vector(5, 12)` instead of `"W2 -> Vector(5, 11)`